# Use marketing cloud to create a custom unsubscription page using smart capture

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api

I saw a few people have posted with similar questions, but I cannot seem to find the answer. I need to create a page from marketing cloud that will allow the user to unsubscribe without taking them to the unsubscription center (the design of this page is poor and does not match branding)

Unfortunately I do not really understand what steps I need to do to get this to work. I have found that I could possibly use smart capture to do this, but the options that are supposed to be available I don't see.

When I add a smartcapture element, I have a dropdown that says "Data Target" which only lists 3 possible options, Data Extension, CloudPages Data Extension and Email Subscriber list. This does not match the explanations that I found in the documentation below.

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/smart_capture_advanced_procedures/creating_a_custom_unsubscription_page_using_smart_capture/

I also searched further and attempted to do what is outlined in this question, however I came to the same barrier where my smartcapture form did not have these options.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000swzCQAQ#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=All&criteria=BESTANSWERS&id=9063A000000swzCQAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your outline above, and the typical process, what you'd do is the following steps:

- Choose "Data Extension" as the target
- Create a "Data Extract", which exports the data from the DE to the FTP
- Create a file transfer activity which moves the file into proper folder
- Create an import activity which imports the file to the list in question (e.g. all subscribers)

Now, the trick here, is to ensure that you data extension has columns that reflect the necessary values, e.g. including a "Status" column with default value "Unsubscribed" (if memory serves)

Also, if you want - you can add some SQL activities to either a) clear the data extension or b) move those from the target DE to another DE (which I'd then use as the export source), so that you only export those who unsubscribed in the last X hours or X days whenever you run the automation.

Hope this makes sense? if not, feel free to ask away ! :)

Comment: Sorry I did not get back to you. I don't actually believed this solved the issue as data extension was not working properly at the time of posting. I ended up writing AMP Script to solve my needs, but your effort is much appreciated.

Comment: AMPscripting would definitely also be my preferred way, instead of smart capture. Happy you found a solution !